# Is there a function for mapping each elem of an iter. seq. to corresponding ones of another?

Tags: python, dictionary, methods

I know that `dict.fromkeys(a, b)` takes an iterable sequence of keys (`a`), but only takes one (optional) value (`None` by default). I also know that `update({k1: v1, k2: v2...})` takes either a dictionary, or something like a list of `(key, value)` tuples. But I have been unable to find a method that looks something like:-

`new_dict = dict.method(lst1, lst2)`
that maps each element of `lst1` to corresponding element of `lst2`.

I am aware that I could use the `map()` function, with, say, a `lambda` as an argument or something similar, but I was looking for a direct (more efficient?) replacement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip the lists together into `(key, value)` tuples, and then pass the result to `dict()`.

```
>>> lst1 = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> lst2 = [42, True]
>>> dict(zip(lst1, lst2))
{'foo': 42, 'bar': True}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for introducing me to zip()!